# Apply NSPredicate to Array which is inside an a dictionary IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, nspredicate

```
@interface Contact : NSObject

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger *cid;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrPhone;

@end
```

I have created "Contact" NSObject for above dictionary which has arrPhone array.

Now I have an array which has list of contact object. Now i need those contact object whose phone array contains number which starts with @"11" (my search string)

I have tried the following:

```
NSPredicate *p1 =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"arrPhone contains[cd] %@)",searchText];
```

But its not working. Please help.

Comment: I have created model class for it and stored in an array. Then I applied predicate on phone array like
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"arrPhone contains[c] %@", @"11"];

Comment: then edit question and show Your code

Answer (score 1):

Since `arrPhone` is itself an array, you need to test whether any of its members matches your search criteria, not whether it does.  So amend your predicate to use `ANY`:

```
NSPredicate *p1 =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY arrPhone contains[cd] %@)",searchText];
```

Comment: This works!! Someone should mark this the answer! kthnxbi

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[collection[@"phone"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] '11'"]];
```